# Resource server and authorization server in OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth2

Can resource server and authorization server be on the same server in OAuth 2.0? Also, Can they share the same database as well?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1

> The authorization server
> may be the same server as the resource server or a separate entity.

Comment: This is just a link only answer.

Comment: That answers exactly the question. What more can be said ?

Comment: It doesn't particularly matter whether or not it answers the question, link-only answers are not accepted here and are generally moved to be a comment.

Comment: This answer would still be useful without the link. The link just serves to show the (authorative) source used. So, it's not a link-only answer.

Comment: Furthermore IETF RFCs are immutable and thus concerns about stale links do not apply.